# How to override performClick() for setOnTouchListener()

Tags: android, kotlin

I have an ImageView with a setOnTouchListener() on it.

Android Studio warns me that "Custom view 'ImageView' has setOnTouchListener called on it, but does not override performClick".

I've looked at answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27462468/custom-view-overrides-ontouchevent-but-not-performclick) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46171379/android-kotlin-ontouchlistener-wants-me-to-override-performclick), but can't see how they work with the .setOnTouchListner method.

How can I get this to work, and keep the accessibility functionality valid?

```
import android.graphics.Bitmap
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.widget.ImageView
import android.widget.Toast

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val imageView : ImageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView)
        val imageBitmap : Bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(application.resources, R.drawable.nice_piccy)
        imageView.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap)

        imageView.setOnTouchListener(View.OnTouchListener({ view: View, event ->
            Toast.makeText(this,
                "Touched at ${event.getX().toInt()}, ${event.getY().toInt()}",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            true
        }))

    } // End onCreate()

 } // End MainActivity
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:contentDescription="A test image to be clicked"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: What is your requirement? Can it be fulfilled by `onClickListener` instead of `setOnTouchListener`?

Comment: [this might help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50343572/6213557)

Comment: My requirement is to get the RGB colour value at the touched point.

Answer (score 1):

Came across this issue a couple of times. It isn't really self-explanatory. When you want to keep the accessibility functionality, there is no other way around this, that I would know of, other than creating a custom ImageView extending ImageView like so:

```
class MyTouchImageView @JvmOverloads
constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null, defStyle: Int = 0) :
    AppCompatImageView(context, attrs, defStyle){

    var point =  PointF()


    override fun onTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        // get your coordinates here
        point.x = event.x
        point.y = event.y

        when (event.action){
            MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> {
                performClick()   // call performClick() here, that is the same as some accessibility function would do
                return true
            }
        }

        return false
    }

    override fun performClick(): Boolean {
        super.performClick()

        // your code that should be executed in onClick event

        return true
    }
}
```

So 2 important steps:

1. override performClick() with instructions to do when onClick is
       called
2. call that performClick() from your onTouchEvent, for example
       on ACTION_UP event